# How to click x number of times in Cypress

Tags: testing, click, cypress

I have a list of objects on my site that all have 'Add' buttons next to them. When the first 'Add' button is clicked, that object is added and the row disappears and is replaced by the next one down. The object name is the same. I want to .click() three times to add the first three objects in the list, before saving. How can I do this?

I'm aware of .click() to click a single object. I'm also aware of .click ({ multiple: true}) to click all the objects on the page. However, I want it to stop clicking after the third time.

Currently set to click multiple times to add all the objects in the list (which is incorrect):

```
    cy.get('#FieldListDialog > div > table > tr > td > button.button.add-button')
       .should('exist')
       .click({ multiple: true });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To hammer click a button you can use this:

```js
for(let n = 0; n < 10; n ++){
  cy.get('#FieldListDialog > div > table > tr > td > button.button.add-button')
    .click()
}
```

The `multiple: true` is used to click several elements, for example to click all buttons on the page.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah basically I want to just 'hammer click' three times, as the first object will disappear and the second object take its place on each click. I wasn't sure of the right term to search for.

Comment: Cypress includes lodash out of the box. So you can just write `_.times(10, () => cy.get("#btn").click())`

Comment: Thanks @KamranEyyubov. There are two ways to access loadash.
a. without import `Cypress._.times([your logic goes here])` and b with local reference to lodash `const { _, $ } = Cypress` and use with `_`

Answer (score 3):

If you need just a few clicks you could also go for this great solution:

```
cy.get("button").click().click().click()
.click().click().click().click().click()
.click().click()
```

*In my opinion this syntax also gives a great sensation of what the user would be doing in this scenario.*

Answer (score 1):

You could also do like this:

```
Cypress._.times(10, () => {
    cy.get('#FieldListDialog > div > table > tr > td > button.button.add-button').click()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments by Kamran Eyyubov and monikapatelIT, I was able to come up with the following to simulate a button mash, using the Lodash library that cypress exposes.

```
  // Fetch a reference outside the loop so it can be referenced inside the
  // loop.
  cy.get('#submit-button')
    .as('submitButton');

  // Simulate a button mash. Click the button 10 times.
  Cypress._.times(10, function () {
    cy.get('@submitButton')
      // The submit button is disabled on the first click, so
      // force is set to TRUE to prevent the test from failing
      // due to clicking a disabled element.
      .click({force: true});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your selector. If you have n number of buttons, and you want to click all of them, then you need to match all the buttons, not just a single one. So look for a selector (e.g. a class unique to your Add button) that matches all of them.
You can then use .each() to iterate through them and break out of the loop when you reach a certain index:

```
cy.get('#your_selector_to_your_add_buttons')
                .each(($el, $index) => {
                    if($index == 3){
                        return false;
                    }
                    cy.wrap($el).click()
                } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You just had to move your assertion after the click and said click until not exists

````
       .click({ multiple: true })
       .should('not.exist');```
````

Answer (score 0):

you could use lodash
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#times

```js
import { times } from 'lodash'

  times(2, () => {
    cy.get('#FieldListDialog > div > table > tr > td > button.button.add-button')
      .click()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find to do this was by using the [Wait](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Syntax) for a number of milliseconds or wait for an aliased resource to resolve before moving on to the next command.

```
cy.get('#FieldListDialog > div > table > tr > td > button.button.add-button')
       .should('exist')
       .click();
cy.wait(500)

cy.get('#FieldListDialog > div > table > tr > td > button.button.add-button')
       .should('exist')
       .click();
cy.wait(500)

cy.get('#FieldListDialog > div > table > tr > td > button.button.add-button')
       .should('exist')
       .click();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// option 1
cy.get('button')
  .dblclick()

// option 2
cy.get('button')
  .click({ multiple: true })
```

Answer (score -1):

I did and command

```
Cypress.Commands.add('MultiClick',(element:string,times: number) => {
    for(let n = 0; n < times; n ++){
        cy.get(element).click({ force: true })
    }
})
```

and then use it

```
cy.MultiClick('[data-cy=qty-product]',2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to contribute to this conversation since any of the previous answers worked for me. Indeed the code detecting the number of clicks looked like this :

```
if (event.detail === 3) {
// do something here
}
```

So the only thing that made it triple click in cypress was to use this method.

```
 cy.get('div.toggle').should('exist').then((element) => {
    const navlink = element[0]
    const clickEvent = new PointerEvent('click', {bubbles: true,detail: 3})
    navlink.dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
    navlink.click()
})
```