# How to click multiple buttons, specific number of times in Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm trying to write a test where I need to check if a list of blogs is rendered in the descending order of likes for each blog. For this, I've created 3 mock blogs in Cypress and want to give them a specific number of likes (3 - 1 - 2) before I test whether they're arranged in descending orders of likes. However, the below code gives 4 - 2 - 2 likes instead of the intended 3 - 1 - 2:

```
it('the blogs are ordered in descending order of likes', function() {

    cy.createBlog({
        title: 'The Perks of Being a Wallflower',
        author: 'Emma Watson',
        url: 'www.blank.org',
    })

    cy.createBlog({
        title: 'The Life of Pi',
        author: 'Yann Martel',
        url: 'www.pi.com',
    })

    cy.createBlog({
        title: 'Deep Dive into the World of Containers',
        author: 'GDG',
        url: 'www.gdg.com',
    })
    
    cy.wait(750)

    cy.contains('The Perks of Being a Wallflower')
    .contains('view').click({ multiple: true })
    .get('.blog-like-button').click({ multiple: true })
    
    cy.wait(750)

    cy.contains('The Perks of Being a Wallflower')
    .get('.blog-like-button').click({ multiple: true })

    cy.wait(750)

    cy.contains('The Perks of Being a Wallflower')
    .get('.blog-like-button').click({ multiple: true })
    cy.wait(750)

    cy.contains('The Life of Pi')
    .contains('view').click({ multiple: true })
    .get('.blog-like-button').click({ multiple: true })
    cy.wait(750)

    cy.contains('Deep Dive into the World of Containers')
    .contains('view').click({ multiple: true })
    .get('.blog-like-button').click({multiple: true})
    cy.wait(750)

    cy.contains('Deep Dive into the World of Containers')
    .get('.blog-like-button').click({ multiple: true })
    cy.wait(750)

    cy.reload()
})
```

The incorrect output in Cypress looks like this:
[image of output of above code in Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDjiq.png)

Comment: The answer here might help you, it’s using a for loop to click a button x times each: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56867153/6135684

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a misunderstanding the `{multiple:true}` option. It means if you select multiple buttons, click them all, but it doesn't mean ***click multiple times***.

The cause is `.get('.blog-like-button').click()` - this selects the "Like" button for ***every blog*** - that's why your numbers are higher than expected.

This is what I would change

- Use `.within()` to restrict actions to the blog you want to affect
- Use `Cypress._times()` to repeat the click
- Add an assertion for each blog to confirm correct count displayed

The following is approximate as I don't know the HTML, but should give you the idea:

```js
Cypress.Command.add('likeBlog', ({title, likeCount}) => {

  cy.contains(title).within(() => {

    cy.contains('view').click()
    Cypress._.times(likeCount, () => {
      cy.get('.blog-like-button').click()
    })
    cy.get('.blog-like-label').should('have.text', 3)
  })
})

it('tests blog like', () => {

  const testCases = [
    {title: 'The Perks of Being a Wallflower', likeCount: 3},
    {title: 'The Life of Pi', likeCount: 1},    
    {title: 'Deep Dive into the World of Containers', likeCount: 2},  
  ]

  testCases.forEach(data => {
    likeBlog(data)
  })
})
```